# Loading CSV file from S3 to external stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

i am loading csv file from s3 to external stage .
some of the fields has "value" , how can i avoid " while loading csv file.

also i am getting  below error :
Can't parse '"2021-03-03 16:43:31"' as timestamp with format 'AUTO'

what should be done to avoid this error?

Comment: It appears all of your data is enclosed with optional quotes.  You should leverage the `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY` option in your file format or `COPY INTO` statement to declare a double-quote there.  This should resolve both of your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports automatic detection of most common date, time, and timestamp formats; however, some formats might produce ambiguous results, which can cause Snowflake to apply an incorrect format when using AUTO for data loading.

To guarantee correct loading of data, Snowflake strongly recommends explicitly setting the file format options for data loading/unloading etc
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-timestamp-input-format